# Updating Html content through loop not reflecting the final value

Tags: jquery, for-loop, dom-manipulation

html

```
<div class="content"></div>
```

array of objects:

```
var obj = [
  {
    title : "burger",
    price : 5
  },
  {
    title : "salad", 
    price : 10
  }
]
```

functions:

```
function addItems() {
  $(".content").html('<div id="title"></div><div id="price"></div>');
};

function addContent() {
  $("#title").text(obj[i].title);
  $("#price").text(obj[i].price);
};
```

Then I am looping through to change the html and the content:

```
for(i = 0; i < obj.length; i++){
  addItems();
  addContent();
}
```

The actual result is the text string from `obj[2].title`

> salad

My expected result :

> burger 5 salad 10

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

there are multiple problems with your code.

1) you addItem function in not adding a item but replacing it. html() is replacing the actual html content with the new one. Try append() instead of html().

2) Your addCOntent is always adding to the same item because you have only one id and that's "title". If you add another item with addItem() you will have two div with the same id, what is forbidden. So you have to add an identifier to your id.

e.G.

```
function addItems(id) {
     $(".content").append('<div id="title_'+id+'"></div><div id="price_'+id+'"></div>');
}

function addContent(id) {
   $("#title_"+id).text(obj[id].title);
   $("#price_"+id).text(obj[id].price);
};

for(let id = 0; id < obj.length; id++) {
   addItems(id);
   addContent(id);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several problems in your code.

**Firtsly**, you are mixing the scope of your functions `addContent`, `addItems` with the scope of your `for` -loop. If you need to use variables inside of your functions, that are only known within another scope, you should pass them to your function. That makes your code much more readable and undestandable. Noone will ever know by you function declarations, that you actually need the item's data within that function

That means, you have to declare your function so that it can work with the paramters:

```
function addItem( item ) {
  // use the item data inside this function
  // also note that i changed the functions name, 
  // since you are only adding one item
}
```

**Secondly**, you are trying to add multiple elements with the same ID to your HTML. That would be invalid HTML, since IDs need to be unique. You are un/lucky since the function `.html()` replaces the whole HTML within the given object so you end up only having one `#title` and `#price` ID. Instead you can use the `append()` function which appends a given element to your html, so your addItem Function gets:

```
function addItem( item ) {
  let html = "<div class='title'>"+item.title+"</div><div class='price'>"+item.price+"</div>";
  $('.content').append( html );
}
```

You addContent function is now redundant and would actualy overcomplicate your code.

```js
var obj = [
   {
     title : "burger",
     price : 5
   },
   {
    title : "salad", 
    price : 10
   }
];

function addItem( item ) {
  let html = "<div class='title'>"+item.title+"</div><div class='price'>"+item.price+"</div>";
  $('.content').append( html );
};

for(i = 0; i < obj.length; i++){
   addItem( obj[i]);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="content"></div>
```